# Difficulty in retrieving Image with URL in a Java .JAR

Tags: java, image, url, jar, embedded-resource

I'm attempting to retrieve an image for a Java Swing icon. I followed some advice here on SO to use URLs to retrieve it from a jar, but I am getting a null URL:

```
URL iconUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/buildings/"+buildingEnum.getColor().toString()+".png");
Toolkit tk = this.getToolkit();
Image img = tk.getImage(iconUrl);
```

My .JAR structure looks like this. I built it using Gradle and ShadowJar.

[image]

Both running it through IntelliJ and as an actual .jar in Powershell failed to retrieve it properly.

Is there something I'm missing? Please let me know if there's any additional information I need to provide.

Comment: afaik `this.getClass().getResource` looks for the resource in the same package (=folder) which that class is in. Can you try `this.getClass().getClassloader().getResource`?

Comment: @f1sh Perfect, thank you!